# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on VirtualBox gives an internal error at the start

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, virtualbox

Installing 32-bit ubuntu with mostly defaults:

[image: Ubuntu Settings]

Gives me the following error:

[image: Internal Error]

I am trying to look for some troubleshooting steps to find what is causing the error. Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: The above does not work. I have tried allocating it loads of RAM and 128 MB video memory. I have also tried installing Ubuntu 12.10 which gives the same error. However, it has worked before, so perhaps it is caused by the recent update of virtualbox.

Answer (score 3):

Most system requirements specifications I've seen indicate a minimum of 512MB of RAM for the desktop edition, for example here:

- [System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

You may first decide to increase the amount of RAM given to the virtual machine if possible since you've allocated 256MB only.

You might also consider giving it the maximum possible video RAM of 128 MB (since it was a Compiz failure the 12MB you allocated might also be insufficient).

Change those settings first and see if it works. If not, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-6</kbd> combination to open a Linux virtual terminal to debug if necessary. (This is of course assuming you're unable to use the graphical interface at all, otherwise you could just open a terminal from Unity.)