# Installation of Ubuntu 13.04 on Virtualbox "breaks"

Tags: installation, compiz, virtualbox

i have tried to install many times the ubuntu linux distro on virtualbox and it worked like a charm. Today i have tried to re-install from scratch the latest ubuntu version (13.04) on the latest virtualbox (4.2.16) but immediatelly after the installation it prompts an error that compiz has "crashed"...has anybody any similar issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/297989/installing-ubuntu-13-04-on-virtualbox-gives-an-internal-error-at-the-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not unusual to experience crashes from bugs not yet fixed with the version you installed from the downloaded .iso installer.

It is therefore best advice to immediately upgrade your guest OS after completing the installation. In case we do not have access to the desktop we can do so from booting to a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) and issue the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

We also have to install the [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745) for Compiz.

This will add considerable stability to our system. However some crashes may still occur occasionally.

Comment: Hi @Takkat, you are correct...after updating my system everything worked almost all right. Afterwards i just needed to install gnome-session-fallback and login with it. The next step is to install the latest VirtualBox additions from the VM and then reboot and just login with Unity and everything worked like a charm !!! I am thinking later on...if my system is stable enough to provide a really thourough and step-by-step guide for installing it from scratch for the rest of the people who have similar issues like me.